# Term for example that is counterexample for "Conjecture A AND Conjecture B"

Tags: terminology, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

I am looking at something where there are two conjectures, Conjecture A and Conjecture B.

I have Example X. It isn't a counterexample for Conjecture A or for Conjecture B but it is a counterexample for "Conjecture A and Conjecture B".

That is, if Conjecture A is true, then Example X is a counterexample to Conjecture B; and if Conjecture B is true, then Example X is a counterexample to Conjecture A.

It is (alas) not true that Example X implies that Conjecture A exclusive-or Conjecture B is true.

It probably isn't natural to bundle Conjectures A and B into Conjecture C, and call Example X a counterexample to Conjecture C.

> Is there a name for such a counterexample?

I have a short note and it would be nice to have a nice title and an answer to the question might help.

Comment: Either: **[(Not A) or (Not B)]** or, alternatively **Not [A and B]**.  I don't know of any tag phrase, normally associated with either description.  You might try **A and B are mutually exclusive situations** or **...non-intersecting situations**, but it is unclear to me, which description(s) are the most commonly used.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of "Conjecture A or Conjecture B is false" but the conjectures do not have such snappy names. Say such a counterexample was called a MacGuffin. Then I would have a nice title "A MacGuffin in Subject S"

Comment: I vote for "Conjectures A and B are mutually exclusive".

Comment: @RobertIsrael the conjectures do not have such snappy titles but perhaps "Some mutually exclusive conjectures in Subject S". If you would like to convert that comment to an answer I can accept.

Comment: When I was a Math major, composing *snappy titles* was omitted from the course curriculum.

Comment: If you give them your own names after the title page you can still work with both ... Are we sure A and B together doesn't have a name C already ?